# Take url as input from a textbox, and return contents of the url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I cannot find a question that does anything remotely similar.
I know how to build a text box in React or HTML, but I'm not sure how to parse the inputs as a URL, returning a display of said content.

Basically I need:
- A text box which takes a URL as an input
- Return said contents of URL 
- Store text in URL in an array

There are a few other things to do, but those have been my biggest holdups.

This is a textbox in HTML:
https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/html/forms/your-first-HTML-form/first-form-styled.html

This is a textbox in React:
https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010

I've successfully set up both to take inputs, but not sure how to display contents of said input. I know there's something called an Ajax request? But the documentation was hard to follow.

```
input = url
display(url)
newList = list(text(url))
```

Comment: when you say contents of the `url`, like parse it and display the domain, protocol and the parameters, or what exactly ?

Comment: so basically you want to set the src of an iframe to the url ?

Comment: So you have a form on your page with a text box and a submit button, and you want someone to enter a URL... then GET request that URL and return the entire HTML of the page to an array?

Comment: Ugh. Sorry this was not clear. So the textbox will take a 'url'. Then I want to display it as a 'text view'. Afterwards I want to highlight common words, but that's an issue I think I can handle myself.

Comment: What @Bman70 said seems like a good place to start. Will look into iframe's too. Thank you for the pointers. I'll update progress/let me know if you have any clarifications. Appreciate it all around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood this correctly then this is what you want,

```
<textarea ref="searchURL" placeholder="Enter URL..." onChange={this.getData}/>
```

```
getData(){
   let url = this.refs.searchFeed.value;
   this.refs.searchFeed.value = '';

   fetch(url)
     .then(response => {
         return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error)
        reject(error);
      });

}
```

Comment: @Cooper Yes it is JavaScript.