# Passing input value to react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a search functionality for my app. It works with API:

```
http://localhost:3005/products?q=[USER INPUT HERE]
```

and .JSON is returned from this. I already have a working component that I want to duplicate and use it for search results display. It looks like this:

```
class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {},
    url: {}
}

}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
    }
render() {
    const { general = {name:"", description:""} } = this.state.output;
  return (
    <BoxTitle>{general.name}</BoxTitle>
        );
     }
    }
```

working alright, rendered this way:

```
let ChoosePage = (i) => {
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('items'))
let urls = [
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774944', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774945', 
    ...
    'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'];
let urls_sliced = urls;
if (i === 0) {
     urls_sliced = urls.slice(0, 4);
 } else if (i === 1) {
     urls_sliced = urls.slice(4, 8);
 } else if (i === 2) {
     urls_sliced = urls.slice(-2);
 }
 let show_items = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(urls_sliced.map((url)=>{
            return(
              <Item url={url}/>
            )
            }), document.getElementById('items'));
        }

        show_items()}
```

this is my input field:

```
const search_box = (
<form>
    <Icon>search</Icon>
    <input placeholder={'Search...'}></input>
</form>
);
```

I'm looking for a way to pass value inputted by the user to function that will convert it to link and use for getting .JSON from API and then render components mapped with this data. Managed to make only this:

```
let url_s = 'http://localhost:3005/products?q=' + input; 

let show_results = () => {
ReactDOM.render(urls_sliced.map((url)=>{
        return(
          <Item url={url_s}/>
        )
        }), document.getElementById('items'));
    }

    show_results()
```

Help is very appreciated here :)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how to pass value inputed in form in last_results() function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take url as input from a textbox, and return contents of the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387092/take-url-as-input-from-a-textbox-and-return-contents-of-the-url)